# Remove Github organization and repository

Tags: github

My github a/c is linked with an organization and a repository too. I want to remove this organization from my github a/c as I've already quit the company and cannot log into it. I need to do this as I was trying to connect GCP Cloudbuild trigger to my personal created git repo, it doesn't work. During the "Authentication" step it shows the organization and the repo residing under it. My personally created repository doesn't even show up. Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue?

[image: Linking github repo to cloudbuild]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked [this support page](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-your-membership-in-organizations/removing-yourself-from-an-organization)?

Comment: Thanks @JoachimSauer! That was quick and smooth. Would you by any chance also know how to connect a specific github repo to GCP cloud build? After creating the host connection, I'm still not able to link the repository I want. In the drop down only 1 repo is listed.